# Error importing nativescript-oauth2 into nativescript vue project

Tags: import, nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-oauth2

In nativescript vue.js project I installed nativescript-oauth2 by `npm install nativescript-oauth2`.

Later I'm trying import nativescript-oauth2 package into project file by `import { TnsOAuthClient, configureTnsOAuth } from 'nativescript-oauth2';`.

When I'm building application I get following error.

```
ERROR in ./auth/auth-service.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-oauth2' in 'C:\repo\digitaltjagttegn-mobileapp\app\auth'
@ ./auth/auth-service.js 2:0-72
@ . sync (?<!\bApp_Resources\b.*)(?<!\.\/\btests\b\/.*?)\.(xml|css|js|kt|(?<!\.d\.)ts|(?<!\b_[\w-]*\.)scss)$
@ ./main.js`
```

I would be great if someone will give me some hint of what to do with it

I've removed `hooks`, `platforms` and `node_modules` folders and rebuild with the same result.

For example `import { isAndroid, isIOS } from 'tns-core-modules/platform';` in the same file working good.

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: As per the docs you need to use npm install nativescript-oauth2 --save   https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2#setup

Comment: I've installed nativescript-oauth2 with npm install nativescript-oauth2 --save on fresh copy  of project and outcome is the same.

Comment: Feel free to hop on to NativeScript Slack.

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Comment: I've created an issue in nativescript-oauth2 repository: https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2/issues/126

Comment: @lstanczak If my answer helped you, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to version `2.4.0` of `nativescript-oauth2` seems to fix this issue.

Comparing the source from both versions it appears that version `2.4.1` is missing a lot of `.js` files in the source that version `2.4.0` has:

```
pkce-util.android.js
pkce-util.ios.js
tns-oauth-auth-state.js
tns-oauth-client-connection.js
tns-oauth-login-sub-controller.js
tns-oauth-login-webview-controller.js
tns-oauth-native-view-controller.android.js
tns-oauth-native-view-controller.ios.js
tns-oauth-utils.js
```